# Getting wrong month in fullcalendar control

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I have embedded the fullcalendar jquery control by using this code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
          var date = new Date();
          var d = date.getDate();
          var m = date.getMonth();
          var y = date.getFullYear();
          var officerid = document.getElementById('officerid').value;
          url = "/TasksToOfficer/Calender/" + officerid;


          var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
              header: {
                  left: 'prev,next today',
                  center: 'title',
                  right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay',
                  border: 0
              },
              selectable: true,
              selectHelper: true,
              select: function(start, end, allDay) {
                  var title = prompt('Event Title:', { buttons: { Ok: true, Cancel: false }

                  });
                  if (title) {
                      calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                                                   {
                                                       title: title,
                                                       start: start,
                                                       end: end,
                                                       allDay: allDay
                                                   },
                                true);
                      var date = new Date(start);


                      var dateString = (date.getDate()) + '/' + date.getMonth() + '/' + date.getFullYear();
                      alert("Date:" + date);
                      alert("Only Date:"+date.getDate());
                      alert("Month" + date.getMonth());
                      alert("Year" + date.getFullYear());
                      if (officerid) {
                          $.ajax(
                                    {

                                        type: "POST",
                                        url: "/TasksToOfficer/Create",
                                        data: "officerid=" + officerid + "&description=" + title + "&date=" + dateString,
                                        success: function(result) {

                                            if (result.success) $("#feedback input").attr("value", ""); // clear all the input fields on success
                                            $("#feedback_status").slideDown(250).text(result.message); // show status message with animation
                                        },
                                        error: function(req, status, error) {

                                        }
                                    });
                      }
                  }
                  calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
              },
              editable: true,
              events: url
          });
      });
```

But as I am getting values of date while saving ,it is shiwing wrong. Let say I have use 4 alerts in this code. It showing , Date as **Wed Dec 14 2010 00:00:00 GMT+0530(Indian standard Time)** , which is not wrong. But if I go for pick the month of this date it must show me 12 , rather it showing me 11 . why this should be ?

I have checked my system date. It is settle to current date. so that should not be issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
date.getMonth()+1 instead of date.getMonth()
```

Comment: yes , I know it will work, I want to know reason behind it. It must be give current moth, right ? This is not the right solution.

Comment: it is bacause of month array it will start from 0

Comment: I agree, but this should be handled in method, right ? so we can think we can blame to jquery for this.

Comment: The issue isn't jQuery. It's JavaScript. In JavaScript, months in the Date are numbered from 0 (for January) to 11 (for December).

Comment: ok, but the normally programmers assumes that it must be handled internally.... I accepted!